# Git interactive commands fail to complete with message "The system cannot find the path specified" on MinGw64

Tags: windows, git, mingw, mingw-w64

I'm trying to perform `git add --patch -- <file>` and the command never completes.  The MINGW64 shell just displays "The system cannot find the path specified."

When narrowing down the cause by setting GIT_TRACE=1 and trying to run some of the component commands, I found that the error is caused by the --interactive option and the same effect is seen no matter what git command is being run.

Setting GIT_TRACE=1 on the following interactive command gives the output shown:

```
$ GIT_TRACE=1 git add --interactive -- .gitignore

19:16:47.185964 git.c:350            trace: built-in: git 'add' '--interactive' '--' '.gitignore'
19:16:47.185964 run-command.c:336    trace: run_command: 'add--interactive' '--' '.gitignore'
19:16:47.215964 git.c:564            trace: exec: 'git-add--interactive' '--' '.gitignore'
19:16:47.215964 run-command.c:336    trace: run_command: 'git-add--interactive' '--' '.gitignore'
19:16:47.345964 git.c:350            trace: built-in: git 'rev-parse' '--git-dir'
19:16:47.375964 git.c:350            trace: built-in: git 'rev-parse' '--show-prefix'
19:16:47.405964 git.c:350            trace: built-in: git 'config' '--get-colorbool' 'color.interactive' 'false'
19:16:47.436965 git.c:350            trace: built-in: git 'config' '--get-colorbool' 'color.diff' 'false'
19:16:47.466965 git.c:350            trace: built-in: git 'config' '--get-color' 'reset'
19:16:47.496965 git.c:350            trace: built-in: git 'config' '--get' 'diff.algorithm'
19:16:47.546965 git.c:350            trace: built-in: git 'config' '--bool' '--get' 'diff.compactionheuristic'
19:16:47.576965 git.c:350            trace: built-in: git 'config' '--get' 'interactive.difffilter'
19:16:47.606965 git.c:350            trace: built-in: git 'config' '--bool' '--get' 'interactive.singlekey'
19:16:47.636965 git.c:350            trace: built-in: git 'rev-parse' '--git-dir'
19:16:47.666965 git.c:350            trace: built-in: git 'update-index' '--refresh'
19:16:47.793965 git.c:350            trace: built-in: git 'ls-files' '--' '.gitignore'
The system cannot find the path specified.
19:16:47.843965 git.c:350            trace: built-in: git 'diff-index' '--cached' '--numstat' '--summary' '4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904' '--' '.gitignore'
19:16:47.873966 git.c:350            trace: built-in: git 'diff-files' '--numstat' '--summary' '--raw' '--' '.gitignore'
```

Trying to add the file without the interactive option works as expected.  The operation only fails when there is an interactive (or patch) option added.

Note that I initially had the following issue when trying to run the command:

```
Can't locate Git.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Git module) (@INC contains: /mingw64/share/perl5/site_perl D:/Apps/StrawberryPerl/perl/site/lib D:/Apps/StrawberryPerl/perl/vendor/lib D:/Apps/StrawberryPerl/perl/lib) at C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64/libexec/git-core\git-add--interactive line 7.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64/libexec/git-core\git-add--interactive line 7.
```

However after copying the Git.pm and Error.pm modules to the perl include folder, the problem changed to the one described at the top of this question.

Finally, as a further attempt at figuring this out I ran the command in a Windows command prompt (cmd.exe) and had a totally different error:

```
c:\code\proj>git add --patch .gitignore

error: wrong number of arguments
usage: git config [<options>]

Config file location
    --global              use global config file
    --system              use system config file
    --local               use repository config file
    -f, --file <file>     use given config file
    --blob <blob-id>      read config from given blob object

Action
    --get                 get value: name [value-regex]
    --get-all             get all values: key [value-regex]
    --get-regexp          get values for regexp: name-regex [value-regex]
    --get-urlmatch        get value specific for the URL: section[.var] URL
    --replace-all         replace all matching variables: name value 
[value_regex]
    --add                 add a new variable: name value
    --unset               remove a variable: name [value-regex]
    --unset-all           remove all matches: name [value-regex]
    --rename-section      rename section: old-name new-name
    --remove-section      remove a section: name
    -l, --list            list all
    -e, --edit            open an editor
    --get-color           find the color configured: slot [default]
    --get-colorbool       find the color setting: slot [stdout-is-tty]

Type
    --bool                value is "true" or "false"
    --int                 value is decimal number
    --bool-or-int         value is --bool or --int
    --path                value is a path (file or directory name)

Other
    -z, --null            terminate values with NUL byte
    --name-only           show variable names only
    --includes            respect include directives on lookup
    --show-origin         show origin of config (file, standard input, blob, command line)

config --get-color color.interactive.prompt bold blue: command returned error: 129
```

I checked my git config files and I don't set this option so I'm guessing it's a default that's set somewhere.

Apart from the obvious aspect of the question (i.e. getting the `--interactive` or `--patch` options to work as expected), I'd also appreciate any advice or tips on debugging this further.  The various TRACE options I used didn't really highlight where the problem was, apart from showing me that it was the `--interactive` option that was the issue.

Comment: While `git config --get-color color.interactive.prompt bold blue` will fail with this exact error, `git config --get-color color.interactive.prompt 'bold blue'` (or same with double quotes) should work. Perhaps there's a glitch in your Perl module.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @torek. I figured that the missing quotes might be the issue there but didn't know where it was set. Your idea that it might be a Perl module glitch got me thinking. I decided to check my version of Git (2.10.1.windows.1) and realised it was a couple of years old now. Upgraded git and the problem went away. Looks like the problem was with my installation of git. So although the Perl module wasn't to blame, it got me looking in the right direction. Moral of the story is that bad workmen don't always blame their tools - sometimes they trust them too much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short - the answer here was to upgrade the version of Git for Windows used.  My version was 2.10.1.windows.1 which is a couple of years old.  I upgraded to 2.19.0.windows.1 and all is now working as it should.

So the issue might be because there was an error in that version of git, in which case hopefully this will give anyone else using that version a heads-up.  Alternatively, there could have been an issue with my installation somewhere along the line, which was automatically corrected by the new git installation.  In that case, consider this an idea of things to try if you are having similar problems.

Not a particularly fulfilling answer - but an answer nonetheless.

Comment: Perhaps this wasn't actually the fix, or this bug is back, because I'm experiencing the same error in 2.33.0.windows.2 which is the latest version at the time of writing this comment. Do you know if you upgraded something else too? Maybe perl?